# Output load capacitance vs max input load capacitance

Tags: oscillator, frequency, clock, flipflop, capacitance

I am currently in the process of building a frequency divider circuit. To realize a lower frequency of 3.072 MHz. I use the: ECS-TXO-3225MV-122.8-TR

For frequency division and reduction I use D-flipflops of the type: SN74HC74D. These are specified with an input capacitance of: TYPE 3-10 pF. The oscillator is specified with a load capacitance of 15 pF.

Now for my questions:

1. what are the consequences if I connect the oscillator directly to the D-FlipFlop? Would this even work directly?
2. does it perhaps need some kind of driver between the oscillator and the D-FlipFlop device.

I think I have not yet 100% understood the  input as well as output capacitance.

Datasheets:

SNx4HC74: **https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc74.pdf**

ECS-TXO-3225MV: **https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/122/ECS_TXO_3225MV-1634330.pdf**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work connected directly, within specifications, provided you don't add too much stray capacitance (more than 5pF, to be specific) on your PCB layout.

If you exceed the ECS-TXO-3225MV-122.8-TR maximum 15pF it will likely still work, however the rise and fall times may not fall within the 5ns specification for the oscillator. There is a maximum clock rise and fall time for the flip-flop, however it's very much longer. Each half-cycle is ideally about 40ns so that would be limiting. In any case, a few pF more won't cause it to stop working.

The 15pF is the maximum load you can put on the oscillator and still get the maximum 5ns rise and fall times.

The 10pF (3pF typical) is the input capacitance of the flip-flop.  So you can easily drive one clock input, and, in practice, probably several at 12.28MHz with no problems.

Note that the oscillator is designed for something like 3.3V supply and the 74HC74 is not fully guaranteed to toggle at 12.28MHz at 3.3V (25MHz at 4.5V and 5MHz at 2V) if we interpolate we get around 15MHz, higher but not particularly comfortable. Of course you can't run the oscillator at 5V, so it might be better to specify a [74LVC74](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc74a.pdf) which will toggle at 100MHz @ 3.6V supply.

Answer (score 0):

The oscillator output is rated for max capacitance of 15 pF and the flipflop input has only max 10pF so that is below the maximum.

1. It would work if oscillator output is connected to one flipflop input
2. No driver is needed if oscilltor output drives one flipflop input

Comment: Thank you for your reply. To be exact I need two D-FlipFlops to quarter my oscillator frequency. So one SNx4HC74. At what point is a driver stage needed. When more than one FlipFlop or more than one SNx4HC74 is used? And what would this look like then?

Comment: @pLukg If you are going to divide the frequency by four with two flip-flops, please think for a moment how the circuit will look like. I don't see what kind of divide by four circuit would require sending the oscillator output into more than one flipflop input, but feel free to design a different circuit which requires sending the oscillator to multiple inputs. The exact circuit may depend on what specific purpose you need it for.

Comment: Hey @Justme, this was my current suggestion to reduce the frequency. 
https://tinyurl.com/2ldua8ny
Within the simulation it works. My explanation was probably a bit incomprehensible.

Comment: @pLukg The screenshot could be added to your question. But as you see, you are connecting one oscillator output only to one flipflop input so you are not connecting it to multiple inputs.

Comment: And after using both flipflops of the SNx4HC74 device, I could connect the output of the second flipflop Q/!Q to e.g. a next SNx4HC74 to reduce the frequency further. But then the oscillator output capacitance no longer plays a role but that of the first SNx4HC74. Do I have this right? Thanks for your help

Comment: @pLukg I am not sure, because it does not matter how many chips or how many flipflops per chip there is, you are still connecting one logic output to one logic input as far as the oscillator is concerned.